# Solving differential equation and obtain expressions for unknowns?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I have the following differential equation

$my'' + \beta y' + mg = 0$ , with condition $y(0)=0$.

I need to solve the equation and obtain expressions for the unknowns.

I have attempted to use the try method of substituting in $y=e^{\lambda t}$ but do not know how to proceed beyond that.

The differential equation is meant to represent free-fall of an object with air resistance that is proportional to it's speed.

Answer (score 1):

Construct $q(t)=y(t)+\frac{mg}{\beta}t$

By substitution

$$ mq''+\beta q'=0 $$

The solutions of above ODE are

$$ q(t)=c$$
Or
$$ q(t)=c_1e^{-\frac{\beta}{m}t}+c_2$$

$c,c_1,c_2$ are all constants

Therefore, with initial condition $y(0)=0$,the solutions of original ODE are

$$ y(t) =-\frac{mg}{\beta}t$$
Or
$$y(t) = c(e^{-\frac{\beta}{m}t}-1)-\frac{mg}{\beta}t$$